# Getting tuple dimensions in Python

Tags: python, tuples, dimensions

Python 3.9.1 64 bit

I need to find the dimensions of a tuple passed to a function. The dimensions of the tuple are not known, but are either one, or two dimensions. Tuples can take the form:

One dimensional, from 1 element to n, examples.

```
(6,)
(1, 4, 15, 34)
...
(3, 56, 102, ..., n)
```

Two dimensional examples.

```
((6,), (13,))
((1, 4, 15, 34), (203, 7, 32, 9))
...
((3, 56, 102, ..., n), (84, 42, 0, ..., n), ..., (x, y, z,..., n))
```

With two dimensional tuples, tuples will always have the same column number (i.e, not jagged).

I'll emphasise, the dimension(s) of the tuples are **not** known when passed to the function, the function must find them. My attempts:

```
from typing import Tuple

def matrix_dimensions(vector_matrix: tuple)->Tuple[int, int]:
    '''
    given either a one or two dimensional tuple, will determine 
    the dimensions of the tuple.

    parameters:
        vector_matrix: tuple
        either a one or two dimension tuple

    return:
        Tuple[int, int]
        number of rows, and columns as a tuple.

        example:
        (1, 4), for a one dim tuple
        (9, 5), for a two dim tuple
    '''

    dim_1: int = len(vector_matrix) # this will always work


    # dim_2 will throw an execption if vector_matrix is one dimension, no matter what
    # test I do for it being there or not.

    dim_2: int = len(vector_matrix[0])

    return dim_1, dim_2
```

dim_1, will always work **but**, for a 1 dim tuple will get the number of column(s), for a 2 dim tuple will get the number of rows.

dim_2, will work for a 2 dim tuple, **but** will throw an exception, for a 1 dim tuple,

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len().
```

I've tried testing, vector_matrix[0], for None, and not int, is object, for loops, nested for loops, to no avail.

So I guess my problem and question is;

How do I test for a second dimension, without throwing an exception if it is not there?

Also, a bit of background, almost one year programming Python, come from a c# background, hence why I type define everything, after searching all tuple methods and attributes from, https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-tuple/, I've seen tuples don't have an upper(), nor lower() functions, bummer!

Thanks and regards, njc

Comment: You can easily check whether `the_tuple[0]` is another tuple or not. OTOH, in my opinion a tuple should never be used for matrix data. Or for vector data, in fact.

Comment: @zvone, thank you. Why the simple right in your face solution, is the one over looked is beyond me. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got options:

Catch exceptions

```
try:
    dim_2 = len(vector_matrix[0])
except TypeError:
    dim_2 = False
```

Check if it is a `tuple`

```
if isinstance(vector_matrix[0], tuple):
    dim_2 = len(vector_matrix[0])
else:
    dim_2 = False
```

Comment: thanks Macattack, option two is noted, and response up voted, answer accepted.